# Looping through API Call

Tags: python

I'm currently in the process of extracting data out of an API through API calls, and obviously there is a limit on the amount of data that you can pull out of the API call. Therefore, I have to loop through pages but everything that I've tried is either looping forever or it's errored out and give me the JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting Value] : 0.

Here's what the json file looks like when there is a next page:

```
     {'Data': {'XRefCode': 'EarningsDeductionAPi',
  'Rows': [{...]},
 'Paging': {'Next': 'NextURL'}}
```

Here's my current code:

```
data = []

response = requests.get('URL', headers=headersAPI, params=params, verify=True)
api_response = response.json()

while api_response['Paging']['Next']:
    api_response = requests.get(api_response['Paging']['Next']).json()
    data.extend(api_response['Data']['Rows'])
```

What would be the best way to loop through all the pages for this API call?

Comment: If the code shown is "looping forever" then it's because *api_response['Paging']['Next']* returns something that is truthy. Try printing the JSON response after each GET. You may be surprised at its content. Also, it seems strange that the first call seems to require some headers (which you've chosen not to show) but second and subsequent GETs do not. If this is a public API, show more relevant code

Comment: unfortunately this is not a public API this is why I didn't share everything. Is there everything specific that you would like me to share?

Comment: Just do some debugging - e.g., print the JSON response. It may not contain what you think it does / should